# Sorting an array by chunks of 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Assume that you have an array and want to divide it by chunks of 3. If the array is..

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
```

...the new array would be

```
let newArr = [1, 4, 7, 10, 13,   2, 5, 8, 11,   3, 6, 9, 12]

// In other words:
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
13
```

The chunking part should be this code (if sorted like `newArr`):

```
let chunkedArr = _.chunk(_.toArray(newArr), 3);
```

...however I couldn't figure out how to sort the `arr` to `newArr` to be able to chunk in the right order. What is the proper way of handling such case?

<sub>*Please note that the integers are just pseudo and I will use proper objects of array.*</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke1c8sa5/2/)):

```
//This version works for variable chunk sizes as well.
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
alert(chunks(arr, 3)); //You can update chunk size here

function chunks(arr, chunkSize) {
  var result = [];
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length / chunkSize; j++) {
      if (arr[i + (chunkSize * j)] != null)
        result[index++] = arr[i + (chunkSize * j)];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

```
//This version only works for chunks of size 3.
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
let subArr1 = [];
let subArr2 = [];
let subArr3 = [];
var result = [];
var i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    subArr1[i++] = arr[index];
  }
  if (index % 3 == 1) {
    subArr2[j++] = arr[index];
  }
  if (index % 3 == 2) {
    subArr3[k++] = arr[index];
  }
}

result.push(subArr1, subArr2, subArr3);
alert(result);
```

Comment: This returns `[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14]` though, so it has duplicate values :/ _Please keep in mind that 13 is not explicitly the final index and it should work consistently for infinite elements_

Comment: Please recheck. It was a minor typo in the second last line. I was appending the second sub-array twice. And yes, this would work for any given length of the array.

Comment: This is also very nice!

Comment: **Additionally:** `result.push(subArr1, subArr2, subArr3);` would actually work pretty efficiently for dividing stuff into chunk of 3

Comment: Thanks! I have made yet another version with plain javascript that can work for variable chunk sizes as well. Please check out: https://jsfiddle.net/ke1c8sa5/2/

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use ES6 `reduce` to group the array into a multidimensional array. Use `concat` to flatten the multidimensional array.

`[].concat(...)` - basically flattens the multidimensional array. Starting with an empty array `[]`, you `concat` each secondary array. Use the spread operator (`...`) to reiterate each secondary array and `concat` each.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
let groups = 3;

let newArr = [].concat(...arr.reduce((c, v, i) => {
  let k = i % groups;
  c[k] = c[k] || [];
  c[k].push(v);
  return c;
}, []));

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Could you explain what `[].concat(...)` is for? EDIT: Nvm, just saw the bit about "flatten the multidimensional array".

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I added a simple explanation about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this it may help you. I also take a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks). Please check and let us know. any thing else you need.

Thanks

Here is the sample code.

`var i,j,resArr,chunkSize = 10;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    resArr = array.slice(i,i+chunk);
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
const original = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
const chunks = 3

function getChunckedArr(arr, n) {
  let sub = new Array(n);
  let result = [];

  for (let i=0; i<sub.length; i++)
    sub[i] = []

  arr.forEach(function (val, index){
    let o = (index % n);
    sub[o][sub[o].length] = val;
  });

  for (let i=0; i<sub.length; i++)
    result.push.apply(result, sub[i]);

  return result;
}

const chunked = getChunckedArr(original, chunks);
```